# is gcm push notifications are slow in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am using Google Cloud Messaging in my application. I am facing this issue. some times i am getting push notifications earlier and sometimes i am not getting even single message also.on that time i am switching the wireless or mobile internet data on and off than the notification are coming.. 
how to get notifications fast from  Google Cloud Messaging server....
please any help me with u suggestions....

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: it's totally dependent on GCM Server. I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its depends completely on the gcm servers. Basically what happens is when you create google api key(gcm key, you tube api key etc ) at google api console it takes time to propogate to all the servers i.e the server where you have created the api key and the server which your using push gcm notifications are different.So at starting you will face some issue,  after words it works smoothly.

Comment: thank you for you answer. I don't understand why GCM is slow/problematic in the beginning but gets better with time. Could you explain or provide a link that explains this? Thank you.

Comment: @Zhubarb i explaied same thing as an answer. please read the Q n A.